# Starting .NetCore and Angular with one config/task in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, angular-fullstack, vscode-tasks

I am trying to optimize the developer experiance for my Application. I have a monorepository with an .NetCore API and an Angular SPA. To start Debugging i was opening 2 Terminals and cd in to the directories to execute ng serve / dotnet watch run and after that attaching the chrome and .net debugger. 
I want to achive this using one lauch config. 
I manage to start the task in 2 terminals but cannot get both debuggers to work.

My launch json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp-SPA"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Launch Chrome", ".NET Core Attach"],
            "preLaunchTask": "run dev",
        }
    ]
}
```

My Tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "run dev",
      "dependsOn": ["watch", "serve spa"]
    },
    {
      "label": "serve spa",
      "command": "ng serve,
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp-SPA"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API"
      },
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: removing "preLaunchTask": "run dev" both debuggers work if the watch processes already started